# fill data by inserting date records in Big Query

Tags: sql, date, select, google-bigquery

I have a table with missing date records in big query, and I would like to first insert missing date records in table and insert score from previous date record, how can this be achieved in Big Query?

Current Sample table view:

```
Row   date      timeStamp   score   
1   2018-01-21  1516492800  0.44013312375
2   2018-01-22  1516579200  0.3821605743
3   2018-01-24  1516752000  0.3397971282666667
```

Expected table view:

```
Row   date      timeStamp   score   
1   2018-01-21  1516492800  0.44013312375
2   2018-01-22  1516579200  0.3821605743
3   2018-01-23  1516665600  0.3821605743
4   2018-01-24  1516752000  0.3397971282666667
```

Basically, since for date 2018-01-23 a record was missing we insert a record and picked score value from previous date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2018-01-21' date, 1516492800 timeStamp, 0.44013312375 score UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-01-22', 1516579200, 0.3821605743 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-01-24', 1516752000, 0.3397971282666667 
)
SELECT date, 
  UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(date)) AS timeStamp,
  LAST_VALUE(score IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS score
FROM (
  SELECT MIN(date) min_date, MAX(date) max_date
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
), UNNEST(GENERATE_date_ARRAY(min_date, max_date)) date
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table`
USING(date)
ORDER BY date
```

with result

```
Row date        timeStamp   score    
1   2018-01-21  1516492800  0.44013312375    
2   2018-01-22  1516579200  0.3821605743     
3   2018-01-23  1516665600  0.3821605743     
4   2018-01-24  1516752000  0.3397971282666667
```

Comment: This is simply amazing @Mikhail Berlyant, thanks for quick and perfect solution!

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this by only generating the date array for the values needed *per row*:

```
WITH t AS (
       SELECT DATE '2018-01-21' date, 1516492800 timeStamp, 0.44013312375 score UNION ALL
       SELECT '2018-01-22', 1516579200, 0.3821605743 UNION ALL
       SELECT '2018-01-24', 1516752000, 0.3397971282666667 
      )
SELECT dte, 
       UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(dte)) AS timeStamp,
       t.score
FROM (SELECT t.*, DATE_ADD(LEAD(date) OVER (ORDER BY date), INTERVAL -1 day) as to_date
      FROM t
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(GENERATE_date_ARRAY(date, COALESCE(to_date, date))) dte
ORDER BY dte  ;
```

I'm pretty sure this has better performance characteristics over large amounts of data.  In fact, I suggested an approach like this yesterday to a colleague trying to speed up one of her queries.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff for your help, will try out your solution for performance analysis on my table. Thanks again!

Comment: @codelessricky . . . I'm curious why you accepted the other answer before testing to see which is better.

Comment: my current priority is not performance, as I don't see my table size growing too large, and something working functionally is my current priority. BTW I accepted your answer too :-)